# Query files from private folders by SOQL to wipe content?

Tags: files, contentversion, contentdocument, content, bulk-delete

My QA users have overfloaded the Developer Sandbox with 234 MB of files.
I try to wipe all the content, however, looks like SOQL query doesn't return all the files even though I can see them in UI.
I need to query content document which are shared with the current user on UI but not shared with the current user on the SOQL.
How can I achieve that and wipe the content on the sandbox?

I tried to use the following code

```
    List<ContentDocument> content = [select id from ContentDocument WHERE ContentAssetId  = null];
    delete content;
    Database.emptyRecycleBin(content);
```

However, it didn't help to wipe content.

Also, if I try to use `USING SCOPE` optional clause with `allPrivate`

```
Select Id, Title From ContentDocument USING SCOPE allPrivate
```

it fails with an error

> [INVALID_QUERY_SCOPE] Invalid query scope: allPrivate

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions.

1. Refresh sandbox from production.
2. Create a permission set `QueryAllFiles` and enabled checkbox `Query All Files` in `App permissions` section. Then rerun your code and it should work.

Also, created [an idea about this](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000K5CRFUA3/fix-inconsistency-in-querying-files-and-reports-from-private-folders).